# Clique number and maximum clique of gcd-based graph

Tags: graph-theory, divisibility

This is from my homework.

Let $Q_n$ be the graph with vertex set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. Two vertices are adjacent if and only if their greatest common divisor is $1$. Give the
clique number of $Q_{10}$ and draw a maximum clique of it.

Comment: Just draw $Q_{10}$..

Comment: Hint: A maximum clique will be primes and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The clique number is $5$. Note that there can be at most one even number in a clique, as two even numbers would have a common factor of $2$. Also note that $3$ and $9$ cannot be in the same clique as $3$ divides both. So not all odd numbers can be used. This gives us a maximum bound of $5$ numbers in a clique.
$\{1, 2, 3, 5, 7 \}$ suffices to show that this is possible.